# How to extend Craft.BaseElementIndex for a custom Element Type

Tags: javascript, elementtype

I have a custom Element and need to modify the Element Index page. I'm attempting to extend `Craft.BaseElementIndex` and register the extended class on my Element Index Page. I'm working on a plugin for Craft 3. Something similar seems to be working fine in Craft 2, but I'm not sure if this is really a version issue or just an issue with my implementation.

Something like this:

```
(function($){
    Craft.MyCustomPlugin.MyElementIndex = Craft.BaseElementIndex.extend({
      getDefaultSort: function() {
          return ['elements.dateCreated', 'desc'];
      }
    });

    Craft.registerElementIndexClass('mynamespace\\elements\\MyElement', Craft.MyCustomPlugin.MyElementIndex);
})(jQuery);
```

The javascript file seems to load however doesn't have any effect on the Element Index page.

If I add an `init` method with a `console.log()` statement, a message gets logged but then the results on the Element Index page don't load anymore.

```
(function($){
  Craft.MyCustomPlugin.MyElementIndex = Craft.BaseElementIndex.extend({
    init: function() {
      console.log('Who cooks for you?');
    },
    getDefaultSort: function() {
        return ['elements.dateCreated', 'desc'];
    }
  });

  Craft.registerElementIndexClass('mynamespace\\elements\\MyElement', Craft.MyCustomPlugin.MyElementIndex);
})(jQuery);
```

Any ideas on what I'm missing?

Comment: Would you mind sharing your solution if my answer didn't solve the problem? I'm interested how you were able to do it - maybe I'll need it in the future.

Comment: I'll try to circle back when I test things out, Robin. Haven't had a chance to dig into this further yet. I appreciate your thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

Not really an answer to your question but some thoughts..
I've tried your code with my form builder and I noticed two things (the first is really obvious)

1. When you overwrite the default `init` function everything will (of course) break because all the important staff happens there, you can make your calls in the `afterInit()` function. [Craft.js Line 3573](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/develop/src/web/assets/cp/dist/js/Craft.js#L3573)

   ```
   // Give sub-classes a chance to do post-initialization stuff here
   this.afterInit();
   ```
2. This function handles the sort for Craft. `Craft.js line 2721` [link to git](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/develop/src/web/assets/cp/dist/js/Craft.js#L2721)

   ```
   setStoredSortOptionsForSource: function() {
       // Default to whatever's first
       this.setSortAttribute();
       this.setSortDirection('asc');

       var sortAttr = this.getSelectedSourceState('order'),
           sortDir = this.getSelectedSourceState('sort');

       if (!sortAttr) {
           // Get the default
           sortAttr = this.getDefaultSort();

           if (Garnish.isArray(sortAttr)) {
               sortDir = sortAttr[1];
               sortAttr = sortAttr[0];
           }
       }

       if (sortDir !== 'asc' && sortDir !== 'desc') {
           sortDir = 'asc';
       }

       this.setSortAttribute(sortAttr);
       this.setSortDirection(sortDir);
   },
   ```

   The important part is: `var sortAttr = this.getSelectedSourceState('order'),` ([line 2726](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/develop/src/web/assets/cp/dist/js/Craft.js#L2726)) and since `sortAttr` (at least for me) was never null in my tests - the `sortAttr = this.getDefaultSort();` is not triggert. This is because Craft caches the sort order for the user but I don't know how/when this happens. However: when I overwrite [line 2729](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/develop/src/web/assets/cp/dist/js/Craft.js#L2729)

   ```
   if (true || !sortAttr) {
       // Get the default
       sortAttr = this.getDefaultSort();

       if (Garnish.isArray(sortAttr)) {
           sortDir = sortAttr[1];
           sortAttr = sortAttr[0];
       }
   }
   ```

And use

```
getDefaultSort: function() {
    return ['dateCreated', 'asc'];
}
```

I was able to change the default sort. Hope it helps a little bit

**Note:** this will break the default Craft caching. Normally the default sort options runs only once, after that is keeps the sort order that the user specified. You could overwrite the function for your tests and remove the always true condition when it goes live for a reliable way to get your function triggert.